# How to read .docx on Android with Apache Poi

Tags: android

I have .docx file in assets folder and use this part of code to to read it

```
  AssetManager am = context.getAssets();

   InputStream is;

  is = (InputStream) am.open("amaretti.docx");

  XWPFDocument hdoc=new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(is));
```

and jars for this are:

```
   poi.jar
   poi-ooxml.jar
```

But shows me an error:

```
  08-27 18:16:31.660: I/dalvikvm(23221): Could not find method           org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTDocument1$Factory.newInstance, referenced from method org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentCreate
```

I guess some jar or classes are missing.

Any suggestion would be useful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, can you plz share code for read .docx files in Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing some jars. In order to read Word 2007 files using POI you also need the following libraries (they're all available in the archive you download from the official Apache POI site):

**poi-ooxml-schemas** (the one you're getting the error about)

**xmlbeans**

**dom4j**

**stax**

According to the official website, dom4j and stax are no longer needed but I found I had problems when I didn't add them.

Unfortunately, you're bound to discover that adding all of these libraries will result in a Dalvik dex error (an Android classes.dex can hold up to 64k of method declarations, which you will cross). The "official" explanation for this is that POI is simply not designed for Android. Unfortunately I have not been able to find an easy, manageable solution for that problem (there have been attempts, some partially successful, of porting POI to Android, but they're too cumbersome for my taste). I solved that problem by sending the Word 2007 files to a remote server, converted them to the old format and returned to the mobile device to be opened by POI.

Comment: Thank you for answer, you confirm my opinion, thanks very much. I read .doc document, but I am afraid if I convert file on remote server I will loose structure of documents, or even loose some data. I will try to delete all classes in .jar I dont need it....I hope it works, thanks again...

Comment: Hi Mikky can you plz share code for read .doc and .docx,xls files in Android. i need urgent

Comment: can you post the entire demo source code for reading doc filee in android using apache poi..