# Android + Apache POI I need read .docx and convert to text

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

i need read .docx and convert to text. i am trying to using library Apache POI but I get some mistakes

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "by.roman.irtov.apachepoi"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.0'
}
```

Application

```
class App : MultiDexApplication() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        MultiDex.install(this)
    }
}
```

Block is reading docx

```
private fun readDocx(){
        try {
            val dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            val yourFile = File(dir, "test.docx")
            val opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(yourFile, PackageAccess.READ)
            val docx = XWPFDocument(opcPackage)
            val wx = XWPFWordExtractor(docx)
            val text = wx.text
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

In line - val docx = XWPFDocument(opcPackage) I catch error ->

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: by.roman.irtov.apachepoi, PID: 8158
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader;
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.buildStreamToNodeMethod(XmlBeans.java:251)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.<clinit>(XmlBeans.java:138)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeLoaderForClassLoader(XmlBeans.java:719)
        at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument$Factory.getTypeLoader(Unknown Source:25)
        at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source:0)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:178)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:184)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:138)
        at by.roman.irtov.apachepoi.MainActivity.openOpenPDF(MainActivity.kt:50)
        at by.roman.irtov.apachepoi.MainActivity.access$openOpenPDF(MainActivity.kt:15)
        at by.roman.irtov.apachepoi.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:22)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/by.roman.irtov.apachepoi-dz-oAIxqfj8GBAesyNnFKA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/by.roman.irtov.apachepoi-dz-oAIxqfj8GBAesyNnFKA==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.buildStreamToNodeMethod(XmlBeans.java:251) 
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.<clinit>(XmlBeans.java:138) 
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeLoaderForClassLoader(XmlBeans.java:719) 
        at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument$Factory.getTypeLoader(Unknown Source:25) 
        at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source:0) 
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:178) 
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:184) 
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:138) 
        at by.roman.irtov.apachepoi.MainActivity.openOpenPDF(MainActivity.kt:50) 
        at by.roman.irtov.apachepoi.MainActivity.access$openOpenPDF(MainActivity.kt:15) 
        at by.roman.irtov.apachepoi.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:22) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

then I try to add library -> implementation 'javax.xml.stream:stax-api:1.0'
and now i cath error ->

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:3397)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$XmlReaderSaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:3087)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.getSaxLoader(Locale.java:3072)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1272)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1259)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345)
        at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source:6)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:178)
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:184)
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:138)
        at by.roman.irtov.apachepoi.MainActivity.openOpenPDF(MainActivity.kt:50)
        at by.roman.irtov.apachepoi.MainActivity.access$openOpenPDF(MainActivity.kt:15)
        at by.roman.irtov.apachepoi.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:22)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
     Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler
        at org.apache.harmony.xml.ExpatReader.setProperty(ExpatReader.java:162)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$SaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:3391)
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale$XmlReaderSaxLoader.<init>(Locale.java:3087) 
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.getSaxLoader(Locale.java:3072) 
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1272) 
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Locale.parseToXmlObject(Locale.java:1259) 
        at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderBase.parse(SchemaTypeLoaderBase.java:345) 
        at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source:6) 
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:178) 
        at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:184) 
        at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:138) 
        at by.roman.irtov.apachepoi.MainActivity.openOpenPDF(MainActivity.kt:50) 
        at by.roman.irtov.apachepoi.MainActivity.access$openOpenPDF(MainActivity.kt:15) 
        at by.roman.irtov.apachepoi.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:22) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585) 
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Who knows how to use Apache Poi correctly?
Is it possible on Android? 
Is there a working example? (Apache POI for .docx to text)

Comment: Hope this helps: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25532662/6076979)

Comment: I tried to connect all archive of libraries Apache POI (curvesapi-1.06, xmlbeans-3.1.0,poi-4.1.0 and other). But the result is the same.
Now i tried next solution 
       ...
        implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.1.0'
        implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.1.0'
        implementation 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-schemas:4.1.0'
        implementation 'org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:3.1.0'
        implementation 'dom4j:dom4j:20040902.021138'
        implementation 'stax:stax:1.2.0'

but it didn't help me. The error remained the same

Comment: @РомаИртов have you found a solution for this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This xmlbeans issue is fixed by https://github.com/apache/xmlbeans/commit/68a790420397a4bced610af951614e53d0bfe26a

This is not yet released but you can get the latest snapshot build from https://builds.apache.org/view/P/view/POI/job/POI-XMLBeans-DSL-1.8/22/artifact/build/

[W/ System err: http://xml.org/sax/properties/declaration-handler when reading xlsx files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56939326/w-system-err-http-xml-org-sax-properties-declaration-handler-when-reading-xl#comment100495598_56939326)

Comment: I tried using xmlbeans-3.1.1. and I added all jar files with poi-bin-4.1.0-20190412.tar (without xmlbeans-3.1.0 it was change to xmlbeans-3.1.1) 
+  implementation 'stax:stax-api:1.0.1'

Now I have new error. When call:
            val opcPackage = OPCPackage.open(yourFile, PackageAccess.READ_WRITE)
            val docx = XWPFDocument(opcPackage) <- This

I catched next error:
org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: The 'namespace-prefix' feature is not supported while the 'namespaces' feature is enabled
 ..onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:268)

Comment: Could you provide full stacktrace? The error looks like something that Android SDK throws (eg https://cat-in-136.github.io/2010/10/handling-namespaceless-xml-file-with_29.html). To be frank, many people ask about running POI on Android and I've never heard of anyone who has succeeded. Have you considered, doing the POI work in a web service and having the Android app interact with that?

Comment: @PJ Fanning: "I've never heard of anyone who has succeeded.": https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android.

Comment: There are issues with newer versions of Android SDK and/or latest version of POI - https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android/issues/44