# I want to convert text of Edit Text to Docx in Android

Tags: android, docx

I want to convert text in edit text to docx format directly and store in Internal Storage .

I tried searching on google but hardly I didn't find anything.

```
   String text = editText.getText().toString();
   String FILE_NAME1 = sample.docx // not working

    //  File file = new File("/storage/emulated/0");
    String pathTXT = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Kibo Directory" + "/" + FILE_NAME1 ;

    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {

        fos = new FileOutputStream(pathTXT); // This is creating file in internal (outside)

        //   fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

       // fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(text.getBytes());

        Toast.makeText(this, "Saved to" + pathTXT + "/" + FILE_NAME1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I am giving name as sample.docx which is saving in docx format but it is not valid one.

Comment: Check this link https://products.aspose.com/words/android-java

Comment: Thanks @AnasMehar for answering ...I want to know that will it work always or its just trail version for some days?

Comment: @AnasMehar I tried implementing lib and adding dependencies to my build.gradle from the provided link but when running it is giving error Duplicate class com.aspose.words.internal.zzZNR found in modules aspose-words-19.9-android.via.java.jar (aspose-words-19.9-android.via.java.jar) and aspose-words-19.9-jdk16-jdk16.jar (com.aspose:aspose-words:19.9)

Comment: It's because you have duplicate libraries which already implemented

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apache POI :

Create a function like this :

```
    private static void createDocx(String[] lines) throws IOException {


    XWPFDocument xwpfDocument = new XWPFDocument();

    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("yourfilepath/filename.docx"));



    for(String s:lines) {


        XWPFParagraph xwpfParagraph = xwpfDocument.createParagraph();


        XWPFRun xwpfRun = xwpfParagraph.createRun();

        xwpfRun.setText(s);

    }
    xwpfDocument.write(fileOutputStream);
    fileOutputStream.close();
}
```

and pass your Text as String array (each line of your text will be a member of the array) to it.

Don't forget to add  [Apache POI jars libraries](http://poi.apache.org/download.html) to your project.

Comment: Thanks @ahooee for answering my question ..... I am not able to import classes like  XWPFDocuments, etc after adding Apache POI jars libraries...Can you help with this?

Comment: Or can you tell how to add  Apache POI jars libraries ?

Comment: Sorry for the late Reply ,Currently  Apachi poi has some issues in Android ... But see this post that maybe usefull for you :https://stackoverflow.com/a/25532662/9406623